# How to Play .PLS Files on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming

I have a problem playing .pls live streaming channel on windows phone 7 media element. i read it on someother post that you need to get into bytes then play it but i am unable to do it as well can anyone help me and tell me how can i play .pls on windowsphone 7 for example i have to stream this:

**http://69.175.103.226:8540/listen.pls**

In my app then how will it do it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't play a PLS file because in itself, it is not a media item but merely a stream reference file that contains links to media content. You need to download the PLS file, parse it out and then read the content that is being passed through it.

You have several options. For example, using [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Or you might decided to download and process the stream - you should [do this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/getting-bytes-continuous) then.

Comment: I used background audio player and set its source to http://69.175.103.226:8540/listen.pls but it doesnot play anything

Comment: @Hamza, Open up that `.pls` file in a text editor and you will see the actual stream URL.

Comment: As @Brad mentioned, and as I said in my answer, *you can't play PLS files directly*. You need to parse out the stream URL.

Comment: you mean to get the stream url out of .pls file right? well i opened the .pls file in text editor and it has this File1=http://69.175.103.226:8540/ in it.. which means stream url is (http://69.175.103.226:8540/) and it doesnot play on background audio player